# CGImageRef cg = [[UIImage imageNamed: Path] CGImage]; Requires a CGImageRelease(cg)'?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-foundation, cgimage

I am trying to read the ARGB pixels from a an image asset in iOS. For that, I need a `CGImageRef` I can use to get its `CGDataProvider`. My question is, if I create a `CGImageRef` using:

```
CGImageRef cg = [[UIImage imageNamed: Path] CGImage];
```

Will I eventually need to call `CGImageRelease(cg)`? If I don't call `CGImageRelease`, will I have a memory leak?

Another issue I am having is that reading the same file for a second time returns an empty image, which I suspect might be because I didn't call `CGImageRelease` the first time.

Comment: Beware of this pattern under ARC. When you don't assign the Cocoa Touch object to a variable, it may die before you get a chance to use the CF/CG object you got from it. This probably won't happen in this case, since `imageNamed:` caches the images it gives you, but you should avoid this pattern more generally until Apple fixes the problem in the compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to call `CGImageRelease` only when you use `CGImageCreate`, `Copy` or `Retain`(Or any such related method with create, copy, retain. For eg:- `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`). In this case, you dont have to do that since you are not doing any create, copy or retain.

Comment: Or any other function with `Create` in the name, such as `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

Comment: @PeterHosey, You are correct. It may not be clear from just that line. I have added that too. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

no, the CGImage will be bound to the UIImage's lifetime

following cocoa's 'create rule': you only need to release what you own (objects from methods named new*, copy*, retain return an ownership)

In a addition any  object from CF, follows the CF create rules (only objects from methods named Create*, Copy*, Retain)

Comment: You're essentially right, but you're conflating two rule sets and misstating both of them. The Cocoa rule set (also used in Cocoa Touch) is that any method whose name contains `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `retain` returns an ownership. The Core Foundation rule set is that any function whose name contains `Create`, `Copy`, or `Retain` returns an ownership. The Cocoa rules don't include `create` (and the CF rules don't include `New`).

Comment: then just edit my answer - I dont get it ... nobody does! ..\

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but my rule is not to make edits that would change the poster's meaning. Fix typoes, spelling, and formatting, sure, but when correcting facts, I make a comment instead, so that the poster (in this case, you) will be more likely to see it.