# iOS - Dirty memory keeps growing

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

In my app, I show many images from URL using AFNetworking to load them asynchronously in my UICollectionView. Probably too many because after a while the app crashes due to memory pressure. But using Instruments, under "All heap allocations", I don't see any memory leak.

However, VM dirty memory keeps growing. I can see many "CG raster data" entries. I'm sure this has a link with my images, but I don't understand what kind.

Is there a way to free this memory ?
If it is a memory, how can I solve it under ARC ? (I don't see any retain cycle)

Thank you

Comment: Are you keeping the images in memory? Show some code and logs / exception trace / memory termination log.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue; my app gets asset manager images, uses them, and after a time CG Raster keeps growing until poof. But I'm not keeping references, and see no sign of "leaks"... not sure who's hanging on to the images. I could alleviate it with smarter caching on my side, but seems that would just delay the problem.

Comment: Ah, just talking about it helped. Thanks for listening! I was doing some CGBitmap manipulations. Every CGCreateXxx() needs a CGReleaseXxx(), not like the ARC objects. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921779/cgimageref-cg-uiimage-imagenamed-path-cgimage-requires-a-cgimagerelease

Answer (score 0):

A little late but I experienced this before when UIImageJPEGRepresentation.

Your best move is to wrap in an autorelease pool

> @autoreleasepool {
>
> ```
> // Code here...
> ```
>
> }

This will release all instances inside the block that have ref count 0. This is good for loops as otherwise your memory footprint will grow until you reach the end of the method context.